# PIVOT en SQL Server

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE CodigoCliente IN (5478,785)
```

La cual me genera el siguiente resultado:

```
Fecha      Monto    NumeroPrestamo  TipoPago    CodigoCliente   NombreCliente
7/8/2023    400          104070      Capital        5478        Alberto Perez
7/8/2023    500          104070      Interes        5478        Alberto Perez
8/8/2023    100          104070    InteresMora      5478        Alberto Perez
9/8/2023    600          104060      Capital        785         Carter Slade
9/8/2023    900          104060      Interes        785         Carter Slade
9/8/2023    125          104060      Seguro         785         Carter Slade
```

Básicamente son los pagos a un crédito que han realizado los clientes que filtré en la consulta. Hasta aquí todo bien, sin embargo, quiero que se muestren de otra forma, específicamente así:

[image: Tabla mostrando resultado deseado]

Entiendo que debo usar `PIVOT`, sin embargo nunca lo he usado.

¿Cómo podría mostrar esta consulta de la forma que necesito usando `PIVOT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debería ser algo así:

```
select *
from Prestamos
pivot(
  sum(Monto)
  for TipoPago in(Capital,Interes,InteresMora,Seguro)
)q
WHERE CodigoCliente IN (5478,785)
```

---

*Aquí una forma más extendida, declarando todas las columnas y cambiando los null por cero*

```js
select 
Fecha,
NumeroPrestamo,
CodigoCliente,
NombreCliente,
coalesce(Capital,0) as Capital,
coalesce(Interes,0) as Interes,
coalesce(InteresMora,0) as InteresMora,
coalesce(Seguro,0) as Seguro
from Prestamos
pivot(
  sum(Monto)
  for TipoPago in(Capital,Interes,InteresMora,Seguro)
)q
WHERE CodigoCliente IN (5478,785)
```

---

El `pivot` tiene 3 elementos claves:

- Una función de agregación (`sum(Monto)` en tu caso)
- La columna a pivotear (`TipoPago` en tu caso)
- Y los valores de dicha columna (dentro de la clausula `in`)

Luego toma todas las otras columnas (las distinta de `Monto` y `TipoPago`) y agrupa por ellas. Y obviamente realiza el pivoteo añadiendo las columnas declaradas en el `in`

Tu caso es el ejemplo más simple de pivoteo, porque por un lado conoces las columnas a agregar (Capital,Interes,InteresMora,Seguro) y por otro se da que casualmente todas las columnas (menos monto y TipoPago) sirven para agrupar (en conjunto), esto no siempre es así y es por eso que en internet te vas a encontrar que en casi todos los ejemplo el pivot se realiza con una subconsulta.

Comment: En la parte en la que usas el `coalesce`, ¿Puede ser reemplazado por `ISNULL`?

Comment: Sí. Ambas funciones tienen el mismo objetivo pero actuan de forma un poco distinta. ISNULL tomará el tipo de dato del primer valor, mientras que COALESCE tomará el tipo de dato según la jerarquía de conversión.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo general, no recomiendo usar `PIVOT`. No solo es una instrucción confusa, sino que además es poco versatil y llega a tener mal rendimiento en caso de tener que usar más de un PIVOT en la misma consulta (por ejemplo si quieres sumar y contar, u obetener máximos, mínimos y promedio, o calcular más de una columna).

En su lugar, existe un método que llamo *Agregado Condicional* (en inglés lo puedes encontrar como *Cross Tabs*)que permite obtener los mismos resultados. Se trata simplemente de incluir una expresión CASE dentro de funciones de agregado para mostrar únicamente los datos que corresponden en cada columna.

```
SELECT  Fecha,
        NumeroPrestamo,
        CodigoCliente,
        NombreCliente,
        SUM( CASE WHEN TipoPago = 'Capital'     THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS Capital,
        SUM( CASE WHEN TipoPago = 'Interes'     THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS Interes,
        SUM( CASE WHEN TipoPago = 'InteresMora' THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS InteresMora,
        SUM( CASE WHEN TipoPago = 'Seguro'      THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS Seguro,
        SUM( Monto) AS MontoTotal
FROM Tabla
WHERE CodigoCliente IN (5478,785)
GROUP BY Fecha,
         NumeroPrestamo,
         CodigoCliente,
         NombreCliente;
```

Puede parecer que es un código más extenso que PIVOT, pero es solo cuestión de escribir la expresión una vez y luego copiar, pegar y modificar por cada línea.